# Apache mod_rewrite returning file as a 404 instead of 200

Tags: php, apache, sitemap

I want to use a php file to dynamically generate a sitemap.xml, the php file lives outside of the document root.

So in the vhost for the front-end site I tried adding a mod_rewrite RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule "/sitemap.xml" "/var/www/elsewhere.../sitemap.php"
```

This works, as in on the front end the generated sitemap is visible but the file is returned with a 404 status code meaning google will completely ignore it. I can't figure out why it's being returned as a 404? Any help appreciated.

I also tried using Alias instead of RewriteRule, and it worked the same, returned the desired output but as a 404.

Comment: Are there any other definitions in your vhost that are sending a 404 status code on a specific condition?

Comment: The only other rules that exist are for www to go to non-www, and http to go to https, nothing exists for manipulating status codes. Bit of an odd one.

Comment: if you place sitemap.php in your document root, and reach it directly (skipping rewriterule), does it respond with 200?

Comment: Yes without the rewrite rule static files like sitemap.xml or sitemap.php will return 200. I can't move the php script I have for generating the sitemap though as it resides in a wordpress theme elsewhere on the server, which is why I reached for mod_rewrite and Alias.

Comment: the php script must set the headers to 404. Try to rewrite to a static file and see if you get the same behaviour

Comment: @Capsule Unfortunately it's not the php script itself, the only header it sets is a content type for the xml and a charset.

Comment: Where is it hosted? I know some cheap shared hosting use weird alternatives to the real mod_rewrite implementation.

Comment: @Capsule A VPS on digital ocean. Don't think there's anything custom in that regard. I'll have to keep digging unfortunately.